# How to remove default underline in MUI typography?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a custom Moviecard component for my React app built with MUI that also has a rather annoying and sticky underline for every Typography component that I use. I wish to get rid of it but have been unable to do so using straightforward methods. For example, setting `textDecoration` to none does not work.

There is no obvious reason for there to be an underline and I have looked through the Typography API to no avail. Here is the return statement for and a screenshot of the Moviecard component that shows my issue:

```
return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        m: 2,
        width: 200,
        height: 300,
        borderRadius: "15px",
        overflow: "hidden",
        cursor: "pointer",
        scale: 1.05,
        transition: { duration: 0.3 },
        boxShadow: 3,
        bgcolor: "background.paper",
        border: "1px solid lightgrey",
      }}
      layout
    >
      <Link
        to={`/moviedetail/${movie.id}`}
        sx={{
          textDecoration: "none",
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: 10,
        }}
        aria-label="See comprehensive details about the selected movie."
      >
        <Card sx={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <CardContent
            sx={{
              height: "20px",
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              alignItems: "center",
              zIndex: 20,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
              borderBottom: "1px solid lightgrey",
            }}
          >
            <Typography
              sx={{
                textDecoration: "none",
                letterSpacing: "1px",
                fontSize: "2xl",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                color: "lightgrey",
                wordBreak: "break-word",
              }}
              noWrap
            >
              {movieTitle}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              sx={{
                p: 1,
                mr: 4,
                backgroundColor: (theme) =>
                  (movie.vote_average || 0) > 7
                    ? theme.palette.success.main
                    : (movie.vote_average || 0) > 5
                      ? theme.palette.warning.main
                      : theme.palette.error.main,
                borderRadius: "50%",
                fontWeight: "bold",
              }}
            >
              {(movie.vote_average || 0).toFixed(1)}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="100%"
            image={
              movie.poster_path
                ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`
                : noimage
            }
            alt={movie.title}
            loading="lazy"
            sx={{
              filter: "blur(5px)",
              "&.loaded": {
                filter: "blur(0)",
                transition: "filter 0.3s",
              },
            }}
            onLoad={(e) => e.target.classList.add("loaded")}
            fallback={
              <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width="100%" height="100%" />
            }
          />
        </Card>
      </Link>
    </Box>
  );
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a codesandbox sample  because i tried as much as i can your code and no underline is shown in my case

Comment: this is the code i tried [codesandbox](<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-lake-rl5hzd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="romantic-lake-rl5hzd"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>)]

Comment: Thank you for your help, you made me realize that the issue was in the Link component instead of the Typography component, which I was initially suspecting and I was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the issue was that the `Link` component that wraps the entire code was underlining its children and overriding everything that the inner CSS did to try to remove the underline. I solved the issue by adding the following code to my global CSS file:

```css
* {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```